# A question from cellular homology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let X be the 2 complex obtained from $S^{1}$ with its usual cell structure by attaching
two 2 cells by maps of degrees 2 and 3 , respectively.
(a) Compute the homology groups of all the subcomplexes $A ⊂ X $ and the corre-
sponding quotient complexes X/A .
(b) Show that X is homotopy equivalent to
$S^{2}$ and that the only subcomplex $A ⊂ X$ for which the quotient
map X →X/A is a homotopy equivalence is the trivial subcomplex, the 0 cell.

I have calculated the homologies and these are:

Case 1 : A is 1-skeleton ,$H_0(X/A)= Z $, $H_2(X/A)= Z\bigoplus Z$ and $0$ otherwise.

Case 2: For other non-trivial proper subcomplexes ,$H_i(X/A)= Z$  for $i=0,2$ and $0$
 otherwise.

But I need some help for the second part of question.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the usual cell structure on $S^1$? I know at least two which deserve that name!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez The one with 1 $0$ - cell $x_0$ and $1$ 1-cell attached via the map $f : S^0 \to x_0$ (the constant map at a point).

Comment: Take it 1 0-cell and 1 1-cell.

Comment: I don't think your computations are correct. For example, if you contract the 1-skelenton (which is the $S^1$ you started with) the resulting space is two spheres attached at a point.

Comment: I have done it as follows X/A has cell structure 1 0-cell and 2 2-cells.Sorry,that was a typo and thanks to point out.

Comment: Your 2nd computation cannot be correct: $H_0$ of those complexes cannot be zero...

Comment: @ShraddhaSrivastava In your second computation I'm quite certain the quotient is path connected and so your computation of $H_0$ should be $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: I am really sorry I should have mentioned that it is reduced homology but I think now it is fine.

Answer (score 4):

I know this a Hatcher HW problem, so I won't give away the answer. But Allen Hatcher himself thought this problem was too hard, and gives an extra hint on this page (you have to scroll down to see it):[Hatcher Additional Exercises](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT-exercises.pdf)

Comment: well,I appreciate that you think it is a homework problem but in actual it is not.Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can find an idea for the solution here: http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/blok1_05/AT-ex.pdf?q=allen-hatcher, page 26.